# Temporary Security Credentials to access Azure Services

Tags: azure, active-directory, acs, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am looking for a feature in Azure similar to [AWS Security Token Service (STS) Temporary Security Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html) to allow federated users access Azure services. We are having support for multiple Identity Providers in our application(Amazon account, Microsoft Account, LinkedIn, Google, Facebook, Github & Twitter). We plan to add support for more Identity Providers in the future.

Once the user logs in using one of these Identity Providers, we want to allow access to various Azure services on behalf of these users. AWS has an option to provide temporary access token on behalf of federated users residing in an external Identity Provider(IDP).

Does Azure AD has any similar feature where it generates a token based on an existing token(from external IDP) and allows access to Azure Services?

Thanks
Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it exactly meets your needs, but have a look at [Azure Role-based Access Control](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/).

Comment: Thanks @Bluesky for your response. My requirement is to be able to authenticate my application using social identity providers and invoke Azure APIs on behalf of my logged in user. This is provided in AWS using their Secure Token Service as described in the link mentioned in my question. I was looking for a similar feature in Azure.

Comment: Azure Insights, Azure Usage/Rate Card API to start with. But in general it could be any Azure API exposed by Azure Resource Manager.

Comment: Still not clear on the scenario.  Does the end-user who logs in with an identity provider have their own Azure subscription, and they are granting YOUR app access to their own subscription?

Comment: The scenario is as following. a) My application allows users to login using various identity providers(Google/Facebook/LinkedIn etc...) b) These users will invoke Azure APIs and I need to invoke those APIs on behalf of these logged in users. c) Since these users may not have an actual account in Azure subscription, I need to get an access token on behalf of these trusted users from Azure. d) AWS provides this same feature and scenario for third-party trusted users to access AWS console. I am looking for similar support in Azure

Comment: I am looking for an equivalent for AWS AssumeRole API (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html)